# what will happen if the broker crashes in Kafka vertx?

Tags: apache-kafka, vert.x

while creating the Kafka Consumer we are loading the properties which  has broker urls.

What will happen if the kafka brokers are crashed and how we can use this kafka consumer in this scenorio. Could you please provide how to handle this scenario.

```
configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, 
        "broker1.server.com,broker2.server.com,broker3.server.com");

KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = KafkaConsumer.create(vertx, configProperties);
```

Comment: Are you asking about handling the scenario where one of the brokers in the cluster is down, or are you asking about how to handle the scenario when all the brokers in the cluster are down?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want to know in both the scenarios. Could you please explain me